# One Note Api rejects Bearer Token, Error 401

Tags: java, apache, apache-httpclient-4.x, onenote, onenote-api

I got a problem with sending bearer token to the One Note API.

```
String returnUri = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf";
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost tokenRequest = new HttpPost(returnUri);
tokenRequest.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
tokenRequest.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(Connection.getParametersForURLBody(), Consts.UTF_8));
tokenRequest.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0");
HttpResponse tokenResponse = client.execute(tokenRequest);
HttpGet getTopFiveNotebooks = new HttpGet("https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/me/notes/notebooks?top=5");

getTopFiveNotebooks.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + Connection.getValueByKey("access_token", Connection.getTokenInJson(tokenResponse)));
```

I got the `Bearer Token` and the header of the `HttpGet-Request` looks like this, if I look at it in debug-mode:

[image: Token in the HtppGet-Header]

But when I try to perform the get, the API gives me a `401 Unauthorized` Error.

My Scope is `scope=wl.basic+onedrive.readwrite`, so the token should have all permissions it needs.

**Update:** If I login into https://apigee.com/onenote/embed/console/onenote/ with my microsoft-account and copy the access-token from there into this piece of code:

```
getTopFiveNotebooks.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Bearer " + acces-key-from-the apigee-console)
```

it performs the get and give me `Status 200` back instead of `401`.

So is my permission scope wrong?

Edit: My Scope was false.

Comment: have you found solution of this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you don't have the right scopes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn807159.aspx

You need at least "office.onenote" to be able to get the user's notebooks.

Btw, if you look at the body of the 401 response, you'll see which scopes are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some cases where error could happen:

1. Please pay attention that string of scopes must be encoded too, so
   instead of `+` you should use `%20`.
2. Also make sure that this function you used, returns anything:
   `Connection.getTokenInJson(tokenResponse)`
3. And try this permission scope which works fine for me:

   ```
   "office.onenote%20office.onenote_create%20office.onenote_update_by_app%20office.onenote_update"
   ```