# 401 error from using bearer token right after completing code flow in onenote

Tags: python, access-token, onenote-api

I checked here [One Note Api rejects Bearer Token, Error 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42001541/one-note-api-rejects-bearer-token-error-401). and my scopes are good.

For step 2 of code flow my "Scopes" say `office.onenote office.onenote_create office.onenote_update_by_app office.onenote_update wl.offline_access` when receiving the `access_token`

so I take the `access_token` and do a `requests`

```
headers={"Authorization" : "Bearer " + x['access_token'], 'Accept': 'application/json'}
r=requests.get( url=url,data = headers)
```

`r.status_code=401`

I earlier used the same `requests` command for a Token flow to get the `access_token` and it worked fine.

Comment: Did u make the second GET request in the same script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `headers` argument to set the headers :

```
r=requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
```

The `data` argument is used to send post data in post requests.

Comment: that worked. I'm not sure why `data=headers` worked that other time.